# Using a decorator to save matplotlib graphs; saved output is blank

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a decorator function `@save_fig` to wrap around a `matplotlib` function (`plot_this()`) in order to automatically save the output.

I can get the decorator to execute correctly and show/display the graph. However, when the `plt.savefig()` is evaluated a blank graph is saved to my directory.

I'm wondering what I'm missing with the logic in my decorator code? The output should be completely reproducible from my code below.

Thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'foo':list(range(5)), 'bar':list(range(5, 10, 1))})

def save_fig(**param):
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            ax = func(*args)
            if 'filename' in param.keys():
                print('filename')
                plt.savefig(param['filename'])
            elif 'show' in param.keys():
                print('show')
                plt.show()
            else:
                return ax
        return inner
    return outer

@save_fig(**{'filename': 'foo.png'})
def plot_this():
    plt.scatter(df['foo'], df['bar'])
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_this()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `show` before saving the figure. The figure that is saved is hence a new empty figure. Since you handle `show` inside the decorator anyways, you can just leave it out.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'foo':list(range(5)), 'bar':list(range(5, 10, 1))})

def save_fig(**param):
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            artist = func(*args)
            if 'filename' in param.keys():
                print('filename')
                plt.savefig(param['filename'])
            if 'show' in param.keys() and param["show"]:
                print('show')
                plt.show()
            else:
                return artist
        return inner
    return outer

@save_fig(**{'filename': 'foo.png', 'show' : True})
def plot_this():
    return plt.scatter(df['foo'], df['bar'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_this()
```